# My computer can not install pip on Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I use Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10 but I still don't have pip attached with Python. I test with this

```
pip --version
```

I have followed the instruction in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ but my computer just do nothing after I type in

```
python get-pip.py
```

Nothing appears, no error, no instruction and now I just don't know what to do to install pip. I found nobody having the same this error.

Comment: Do you have get-pip.py in the same folder where you're running the command?

Comment: What is the output of the command `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: `python3 -m pip --version` will let you know if pip is installed, if it's installed but not directly  accessible, you'll have to add pip to PATH

Answer (score 1):

Pip comes with Python 3.8, but is located in the Python38/Scripts directory which isn’t added to the PATH environment variable by default on Windows. What is installed in the PATH is the Python Launcher...a tool to manage multiple installations of Python.

Run `py -0` to see installed Pythons, and `py -m pip` to run pip under the latest version of Python installed.

If you do have multiple Python versions installed, `py -3.8 -m pip` will run pip under that specific version of Python.

Note that if you watch the installer, you do have the option to add the Python installation directory to the path, but if you plan to ever have multiple versions of Python installed it isn’t recommended.

Comment: It works. Your answer is so helpful. Thank u so much

Comment: @Long Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If an answer is useful, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.  See [What do I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Does pip come with ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the get-pip file from this link. https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. Change the current path of the directory in the command line to the path of the directory where the above file exists.
3. Run the command :`python get-pip.py`
4. One can easily verify if the pip has been installed correctly by performing a version check on the same. Just go to the command line and execute `pip -V`
5. If still not working then edit the path variable in settings. ref link. ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)