# How do I fix pip?

Tags: python, pip

When I installed python it said that it would have installed pip but I didn't get it to work. I searched the web and found the get-pip way of installing. But unfortunately It doesn't work for me. My CMD doesn't give a reaction on any commands regarding this (see the picture) it also doesn't install pip. Does someone have a fix for this problem? I'm using python 3.9 and the pip file is from (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to set the environment variable to see it is fixed or not. The easiest way and not recommended way to fix it is to uninstall python3 and reinstall it again. During reinstalling, it was a check box for adding environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! it look likes this it the fix I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need it install pip separately you can use something like this (on linux):

```
python3 -m pip install nameoflibraryyouwanttoinstall
```

(on windows):

```
py -3 -m pip install nameoflibraryyouwanttoinstall
```

but its recommended to work in a python virtual environment. [Here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) is a good article on how to setup a virtual environment.