# How to install pip without errors?

Tags: python, pip

Today i've tried to create my own Telegram bot(i'm new at python), and i wanted to install pyTelegramBotAPI, i used 'pip' but it wrotes
`pip is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.`
Who can explain me how to use 'pip' in cmd correctly, without this errors?
Thanks for attention!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pip+is+not+internal+or+external+command%2C+executable+program%2C+or+batch+file

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have python installed.
type the following command

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then in the same directory

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Hello! Thx for trying to help, but when i'm typing ```python get-pip.py``` cmd not writing anything, and just sending me to the new line. What could be problem?

Comment: What happens when you type "python" and press enter?

Comment: when i'm typing "python" and i pressing enter. It opens Microsoft Store, and sending me to Python 3.8 application on Microsoft Store

Comment: just download python from the following link https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Comment: pip will also be installed just make sure to check the box that adds them to path

Answer (score 1):

It's because your probably not add python into you PATH, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/14516256

Comment: It's easier to reinstall pip and it would add it automatically to the PATH

Comment: Effectively ...

Comment: Hello! Thank you for trying to help me, but i've tried all ways in the discussion, that you send me, but these ways are not helpful for me :(

Comment: Sorry for you, you can re execute your python setup, go to modify > make sure "pip" is enabled, next and enable "add Python to environement", install.