# How to solve python/pip/pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command | python command error after changing path?

Tags: python

I. Have installed python 3.7.8 on windows 10. But when I run the commands python/pip/pip3 from command prompt it gives an error
python/pip/pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command | python command error
Thought I have changed the path on user variables as python's location. I have no permissions to change the system path
What can I do now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add python to the Windows path environment variable.

Check [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) resource to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel -> add/remove programs -> Python -> change-> optional Features (you can click everything) then press next -> Check "Add python to environment variables" -> Install

enter image description here

I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) specially the image ....