# How to install pyinstaller (windows)

Tags: python, windows, type-conversion, pyinstaller, exe

I want to convert .py files to .exe files so I can execute them on a webpage. However. every method of doing this involves pyinstaller which I do not know how to install. Could someone either explain the procedure to get pyinstaller OR tell me if there are any other methods to convert .py to .exe without using pyinstaller

Comment: [how to install pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing Pyinstaller**
Installing pyinstaller is pretty simple and straight forward. All you gotta do is `pip install pyinstaller` or `python -m pip install pyinstaller` (obviously you have to make sure that your python and pip are in `PATH`).To check if pyinstaller got installed correctly, simply type `pyinstaller` in your cmd, if no errors appear, it means, you have pyinstaller installed. If for some reason, pyinstaller installs correctly but still doesn't work, you might want to add it in your `PATH`. You can consider adding `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` to the `Path`.
**Using Pyinstaller**
To convert the `.py` file into a `.exe` file, you can run the following commands (Make sure you are in the same directory as your python file) - 
`pyinstaller file_name.py` - Simply converts your python file into an executable. This will create a few folders and files, and when you will run your `.exe` file, it will open up console and run your script.
`pyinstaller -w file_name.py` - By adding a `-w`, console will no longer appear while running your `.exe`.
`pyinstaller -F file_name.py` - By adding a `-F`, only one folder will be created, which will be containing your `.exe` and no other files.
`pyinstaller -i icon.ico filename.py` - By adding a `-i`, you will be able to add a `.ico` file as your icon.

And of course you can use flags in combination to achieve even better results.

**[External Links]**
Using pyinstaller - https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options
Installing pyinstaller - https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#installing-in-windows
Working of pyinstaller - https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have one issue, I have just installed pip onto my desktop but it is not in PATH and I don't know how to change it so it is in PATH. Any tips?

Comment: To add pip to your path, just search for `pip.exe` and open its file location, and copy the path. Now open "Environment Variables" and add the copied path to it. I will post a link below this comment which will take you to a more detailed solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top