# Installing pip using command prompt raises error

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to download BeautifulSoup for Python. However, when I use this in command prompt;

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I receive this error;

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Am I doing this wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you install pip? What version of python?

Comment: You could use the full path to your pip binary.

Comment: Clearly you are doing something wrong, or it would work the way you expect. The problem is the same as if you were told that anything else were `not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. You don't have a programming question; you have a question about how to use your computer.

Comment: How do I use the full path to my pip binary?

Comment: hello there! you should first try to search for the error...a similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the command

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

would be the preferred method. I had similar problems before. If that doesn't work i'd be glad to help further.

Also a quick search returned ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) which may be of more use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I try to run the above code, I get the error `Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.` Any fixes?

Comment: @Autumn I'm rather new to this aswell but I would recommend you ensure you have python downloaded and appended to your systems PATH environment variable. That way your system can find python when you call it as above. As most posts suggest, going to [link] (https://www.python.org/) and following the download instructions should correct the issue. When downloading there should be an option you can check to add python to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: By opening the Python downloader and modifying to add Python to environment variables, the code worked. thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found a fix:

1. Go to the Python installer
2. Click 'modify'
3. Click 'next'
4. Check 'Add Python to environment variables'
5. Click 'install'

I hope this works for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to verify which version of Python you have running.  I had a similar issue (I'm using Mac) and the fix was using "pip3" in place of "pip" for the commands.

example: pip3 intall (module)

Not sure if this will help, but it helped me ha ha.