# VS Code Python Setup

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am trying to set up VS Code for running python and I have installed Python 3.9.6 , the Python extension in vs code, coderunner extension in vs code, and also added the python interpreter path in Environment Variables. Still when I run the simple print code, it gives no output.

Also the pip command gives an error.

[image]

Can someone explain how to fix this and keep in mind I am a beginner.

Comment: Perhaps an absurd question but have you installed `pip`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

**First one:**

You have not saved your python file, as it has a white circle on the left in the python file name.

[image]

You can add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
```

**Second one:**

You probably have not select pip when you install the python. You can try to install the pip whit this command:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Comment: related to the first problem: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the correct directory using this command:

```
cd "path/..."
```

and then directly try using:

```
python vscode.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't added `pip` to your system path. But still, you can use pip as `python -m pip`. Just to ensure pip is installed properly, type `python -m pip --version`. If you get the correct version info, you can refer to the link below to add it to your system path.

[Add pip to your system path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: ok i have added pip to the system path now, but now it gives a different error:
PS C:\Users\aryan\Desktop\Computer Science\Python\Python Tutorial Folder> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python 3.9.6\python.exe"  "C:\Python 3.9\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Aryan: You don't want to add `pip` to the system path. What's needed is to add the *path to the directory* it is in to system path. i.e. `C:\Python3\Scripts`

Comment: @martineau 
yeah i meant this only i added exactly what you told into the system path.
but it still shows the above error in the comment.
also why does vs code show no output when i print ?

Comment: @Aryan: I don't know why nothing it printed—perhaps vs code is not installed or setup properly.