# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, cmd, pip, environment-variables

I added python to path, and first pip -- version worked, but after that it doesn't recognize pip and I can't install packages. Sometimes even python is not recognized but sometimes is. What is going on??? The environment variables look good.

Comment: Have you tried what this user suggests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/5186384? "you will need to start a new cmd.exe instance after entering the above command in order to utilize the new environment variable."

Comment: edit your question share your environment path with us please explain more

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the error code comes due to the `get-pip.py` file not being in the directory of the python. Try checking it below:
https://appuals.com/fix-pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/.
Also check if the pip is in the correct path as the environment variable.