# Incorrect output when I type "py get-pip.py" in cmd

Tags: python, windows

So I have that output when I type "py get-pip.py" or "python get-pip.py"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4iBV.png)

When I type "python --version" I had this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjj3.png)

And when I type "py --version" I had this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLWZe.png)

I tried to reinstall python, search for leftover python files after deletion, and nothing helps.

Comment: Python 3.x has pip bundled in, you shouldn't need to run `get-pip.py`. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: But i had this https://imgur.com/a/jaoGAWN that means "pip" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file.

Comment: What if you try `python -m pip`

Comment: Output is just "Python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows? Based on my experience, try to download Python directly from their website https://www.python.org/downloads/ and not from the windows store.

Comment: That setup file was dowloaded directly from website, not from Windows Store

Comment: Maybe you already have pip installed. Try typing pip --version into the command prompt.

Comment: No, output is: "pip" is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file"

Comment: When you reinstalled python, did you check the boxes under Optional Features in the installer? If not, you might need to add the path of your pip to your path system variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/17471835

Comment: I tried type "py -m pip" and it works, thankyou for help!