# Why when I want to use pip, terminal return me 'no function'?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pip, pygame

I wanna use the pygame module ( i'm on VSCODE ), so i'v tryed to use " pip install pygame and the terminal return me that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKan.png)

Can someone to help me !? :/

Comment: Since you are asking on the english stack overflow site, it might be helpful if you would [edit] your question to include the english translation of the full error message so we can better understand and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: It seems `pip` is not on your path or not installed. What about `python -m pip install pygame`; does that work?

Comment: You either do not have `python` or `pip` installed, or the correct path variables are not set.

Comment: In the future, please paste error messages as text instead of images (and in english), text is more easily accessible

Answer (score 0):

Your pip script is not globally recognized, you can forward to this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) or [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-do-i-set-system-variable-path-for-python-on-windows/) one for help or just open command prompt and go to your python folder using "**cd pathtoyourpythonfolder**" default Python path on Windows is *C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python"yourpythonversion"\Scripts* there execute your pip install command..

Comment: ok thanks a lot it's working ^^ thanks you :)