# I can't figure out how to download or use pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm a beginner using youtube videos. I'm trying to learn to automate form's

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import pandas as pd
```

I'm on window's and I've tried using anaconda, along with using pip install pandas.

Comment: What error are you getting when you run `pip install pandas` command? It would help answering the question. But you may check if the environment variables are set correctly for python and pip. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter and Pandas are two separate packages. You can do: `pip install tk` to install Tkinter and `pip install pandas` to install Pandas. Then in your code you should be able to import them separately like so:

```
import tk
import pandas as pd
```

You can then reference Tkinter as `tk` and Pandas as `pd`

You could also do:

```
from tk import *
from pandas import *
```

Which would allow you to have access to all of the libraries' attributes without having to use `td.some_attribute` or `pd.some_attribute`

Does that help?

Edit:
It seems that Tkinter cannot be installed by pip at this point. It looks like the `tk` package is actually the TensorKit package.

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed by `pip`.  The [`tk`](https://pypi.org/project/tk/) module installed by `pip` is not `tkinter`.  Check clearly before posting answer.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, I will edit the answer.