# Why 'pip' stopped working even though it was working fine before?

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip, virtualenv

I am a bit new to programming and have been learning for a few weeks now. I am following Corey Schafer basic python videos and in the middle of his Django Series. To run the server, I run a virtual env.
In cmd (in the project directory) I type:

1-pip shell

2-python manage.py runserver

The server runs and I work on the project.

**Not Today.** When I wrote pip shell, it gave me an error that: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73CjJ.png)

I reinstalled Python after uninstalling it. pip is installed on my system. I added a new variable from the python folder (scripts) in my system. I did not work and it's still showing me the same error.

Comment: Why did you create a virtual environment though? You wouldn't need one if you're new to programming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you don't put the correct path in your PATH environment variable in window.
Also, in your picture, it looks like you didn't activate your `virtualenv`, you can see samples from [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activating-a-virtual-environment)

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: How do I do that? Do you mean path of my django project? I did the same things that I have been doing for past 2 weeks.

Comment: To setup path you can ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/9965384)

Comment: Please ignore the referenced answer although it has 682 upvotes as it corrupts the __user__ environment variable `Path` and so corrupts all __local__ environment variables `Path`. It is an absolute __NO GO - NEVER EVER__ to use value of __local__ `Path` referenced with `%PATH%` to define __user__ `Path` with command __SETX__ which should be additionally used with care as it does not support values longer than 1024 characters. Click on Windows Start button, type `environment` and click on __Edit environment variables for your account__ to use the GUI to configure __user__ `Path`.