# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Trying to install Django.
Tried copying pip's address to the PATH in environment variables.
Any ideas?

C:\Users\91700>pip --version
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Have you installed Python via `Microsoft Store`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to type:

```
python -m pip <args>
```

Because `pip` is not in the `Path` Environment Variables

Comment: <args> contains the location of pip?

Comment: These are the two response I got for that-
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
AND
...site-packages\pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user12192649 <args> ist the what you want to do with pip, like: `pip install numpy`

Comment: Okay, I got the same errors that I posted previously, I dont understand what the issue is

Comment: Have you tried using the powershell?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm relatively new to this form of errors. I've mostly scripted on spyder and vscode. If possible to type out a step-by-step, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: You are using Windows right? Search for the powershell in the searchbar. Try to execute the command `python --version` there

Comment: I got this when I ran it in powershell
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Okay It's fixed. I reinstalled python IDE. The IDE's path was wrong in the enivronment variables. That's why it wasn't recognizing. Thanks for your help though. Put me in the right train of thought

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
py -m pip install Django
```

Comment: please explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: I understand that you're excited about `py -m pip install` ing stuff. Maybe you just learned about it. I don't know. But you've submitted several such answers with no explanation. (No, "it worked for me" is not an explanation.) To make decent answers, please actually address the problem presented in the questions.