# How do I install sentence transformer using spyder

Tags: python

My organization policy doesn't allow me to install anaconda. So they installed only spyder 5.0.1 in my system. By only spyder mean, I don't have conda prompt in my system. I'm trying to install sentence transformer using the command prompt in my window 10

```
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```

But I got error message

```
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried to check if python is installed python path set in system using

```
python
```

in command prompt. It's opening Microsoft store. But

```
import pandas
```

statement is working in spyder.
Can you suggest me how do I install sentence transformer under this condition?

Comment: try this `py -m pip install [packagename]`

Comment: [pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)