# Why do I get a syntax error when running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install something in a folder called "requirements.txt". The README says that `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` is required.

When I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` in python 3.10 it gives me a syntax error.

[image: Readme]

[image: Command I entered]

Comment: Meanwhile, the short uninformative answer is: you are typing the command at the Python prompt: it should be typed at the shell prompt (CMD on windows).

Comment: it says that pip3 is not an operable internal or external command or batch file

Comment: As for your new error: ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

To use pip like this you should use it from command promt. Have a look at [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/)

Comment: that link doesn't exist?

Comment: @adrianh, Sorry, now it works

Answer (score 1):

1. The command should be run from the shell, not from within the Python interpreter.
2. Run it without the back ticks (`` ` `` ). The README is in a Markdown format (".md"), and the ticks are used for formatting. Use an editor which can interpret Markdown files.