# Cannot install pip (matplotlib) on windows in pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

tried program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([1, 8])
ypoints = np.array([3, 10])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

pip is now installed, after reading michael s question
the "pip install matplotlib    " works

however the same thing python error is occuring

```
C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\EMC2.00\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/M0182965/PycharmProjects/EMC2.00/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\EMC2.00\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You just have to install pip before using it https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

Comment: doesnt work sadly

Comment: why it doesn't work? edit your question with all the steps following the tutorial that you have executed and at which point it fails. What does the console show when you do `pip help` after having executed the previous commands in the tutorial?

Comment: This looks more like a pip problem than matplotlib. Seems like `pip` is not defined in your PATH. Look up how to add variables to your PATH

Comment: how do I do this

Comment: In the tutorial you have clearly a `Step 4: Add Pip to Windows Environment Variables`. Did you even read the tutorial I linked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

pip install does not work for the virtual environment for the newest pycharm. You need to install via project interpreter for every project individually.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `pip` to your environment variables. Press your Windows icon on your keyboard, then start typing "variables". Click on "Edit environment variables" (pictured below):

[image]

In your environment variables, click on "Path" then click "Edit". In the edit window, click "New" then paste your path to your pip executable, which looks to be `C:\Users\M0182965\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` . Look at my path as an example (the highlighted one is where my pip executable is):

[image]

Then just keep hitting "Ok" until you're out of all the windows. Open a fresh  terminal and try `pip install` again. You shouldn't have to restart your computer but try it if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: no, i did not..