# Everytime i try to install Django using "pip install django" on my command prompt why does this come up?

Tags: python, django

pip install Django

'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an error you'll have to face multiple times in the future. It's pretty self-explanatory. It means that 'pip' does not exist in your system. To fix this either: **1. Reinstall python (using the installer) and make sure that you've checked the 'pip' checkbox** OR **2. Download 'pip.exe' manually and then add it to 'PATH'**.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Tony has said. you should either reinstall python but since you are trying to use pip already. I am going to guess you already have python and if you do then find the python location (default should be: `C:\program files (x86)\Python3\bin`) and then add to path.