# HeIp with pip and setx

Tags: python, github, pip, echo, setx

I am trying to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` but it says `pip` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I searched and learned i need to add it to my path.

I used `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"` and when I run `echo %PATH%` it says

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Python34\Scripts`

However, when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` it still says `pip` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Can someone please help me?

If you can help me, I'm trying to install and run
https://github.com/simonfarah/tiktok-bot

Comment: You might want to format your question to make it readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it looks like you are running version 3.4 of Python? Is there a reason for not running a newer version like 3.12?

Second, Python 3.4, if that's the version you are running is deprecated since ~2019 and PIP in not running well/at all on Python 3.4.

Third thing, how have you installed PIP and Python?

Comment: I also applied an edit to your original post, that makes it more readable for us all in the community.

Comment: Uh I'm running the latest uptade on python.org and I never downloaded pip. Where do I download it?

Comment: Follow this installation manual for PIP, just choose Windows
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/