ModuleNotFoundError in installing pip
i can't run pip on python 3.12,i used to use 3.10 then installed 3.12 . it installed successfully but when try to run it command says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package"
i tried this way:
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
thed edited path of script using system environment

"it installed successfully": what OS is this and exactly how did you install it succesfully and how are you running it?

what os is this? and do you have a py-env package which is good practice if you have different python -versions installed.

There may be a conflict between the installed version and that script. BTW, why are you using what looks like a hacker's script?

it is windows 11

i don't have py-env,what is hacker's script? i am trying to install pip to get pipenv so that i can use django

How about reinstalling python with selected option "Add pip to PATH"?

if i reinstall python , all my program will be gone

@MuhammadEjazBinNayeem The packages you've installed will be gone, but the programs you've written will not.

@NOT_FOUND You can add pip to PATH without reinstalling Python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command
